# PHP Soapclient call generate

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

I am trying to generate the params for below XML, but its not working. I doubt how I convert this to PHP array in `$params`, any help is appreciated

```
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <tem:GetServicesforPincode>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:pinCode>695587</tem:pinCode>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:profile>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <sapi:Api_type>S</sapi:Api_type>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <sapi:Customercode>099960</sapi:Customercode>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <sapi:LicenceKey>9b40edffc20ce2e6fc1462a30fc48181</sapi:LicenceKey>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <sapi:LoginID>BLR00132</sapi:LoginID>
            <!--Optional:-->
         </tem:profile>
      </tem:GetServicesforPincode>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I tried like this:

```
$params = array(
    'pinCode' => array (
        "695587",
    ),
    // 'pinCode' => '695587',
    'Profile' =>  array(
        'Api_type' => 'S',
        'LicenceKey' => '9b40edffc20ce2e6fc1462a30fc48181',
        'LoginID' => 'BLR00132',
        'Version' => '1.3'
    )
);
$wsdl = 'http://netconnect.bluedart.com/Ver1.8/Demo/ShippingAPI/Finder/ServiceFinderQuery.svc?wsdl';
$options = array(
    'uri'=>'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/',
    'style'=>SOAP_RPC,
    'use'=>SOAP_ENCODED,
    'soap_version'=>SOAP_1_1,
    'cache_wsdl'=>WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
    'connection_timeout'=>15,
    'trace'=>true,
    'encoding'=>'UTF-8',
    'exceptions'=>true,
);
try {
    $soap = new SoapClient($wsdl);
    $data = $soap->GetServicesforPincode($params);        
}
catch(Exception $e) {
    die($e->getMessage());
}
print_r($data);
die;
```

Comment: 1. If you're using wsdl you don't have to set uri param. 2. You forgot to pass ´$options ´ to soapclient so it's useless anyway. 3. What does it mean not working?

Comment: @mx0, evenif I pass $options its not working. Above code is expected to give a result, but I am not getting any result (Invalid Pincode is the result I am getting now). But when I pass the above values using SOAP UI I am getting correct results.

Comment: @mx0, is there any error in how I pass pincode? 'pinCode' => array (   "695587",   )

If I pass like this 'pinCode' => '695587', I will get this error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."